# Likelihood ratio tests on linear mixed effect models

Tags: r, likelihood-ratio, mixed-model

I am currently running some analyses on a linguistic data set with a mixed effect model. The problem is, I think that one random factor should be excluded while my colleague thinks it should be included. The two options are:

```
lmer(intdiff ~ stress * vowel_group + (1|speaker) + (1|word), data)
lmer(intdiff ~ stress * vowel_group + (1|speaker), data)
```

How do we check which model best fits our data set? It was suggested that I use a likelihood ratio test, but as far as I can tell, there isn't a function in R that can be applied to 2 linear mixed effects models. Is there another way to tell which model is more predictive?

Thanks

Comment: Store your first model in `fit1` and your second model in `fit0` then type `anova(fit0,fit1)` but you need to fit with the `ML` method, not `REML`

Comment: "fits best" and results of significance tests are not necessarily particularly related  concepts. What do you really mean by 'fits best' in this case?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I was thinking that that was true for LRTs on the fixed effects, but that for tests on the random effects it was still acceptable to use REML. I quickly tried just now to find a source for this and couldn't, but certainly I feel that I have been led to believe this. Not so?

Comment: @Jake that's possible. The easiest way to check consists in trying `anova(fit0,fit1)`:)

Comment: @Jake Glen_b's comment is pertinent. A likelihood ratio test is not really a test for "better fitting".

Comment: At first thought I would go with Stéphane's original intuition on this; I would also use 'pvals.fnc' in the 'languageR' package to get pMCMC-values to see it they convey similar information. I would also assume that just comparing the AIC scores of the ML-fitted models' is will give you an idea if it's worth including that random effect or not.

Comment: @Shakesbeery: Check Bayeen's on :[Mixed-effects modeling with crossed random effects for subjects and items][1] if you haven't done already. It is really a classic on the matter. And finally if you use 'pvals.fnc' that I mentioned earlier you'll be able to see your random effects standard deviation, if those are below a JND (just-noticable-difference) threshold most probably they won't really matter for your modelling procedure anyway.

[1]: http://www.ualberta.ca/~baayen/publications/baayenDavidsonBates.pdf

Comment: I think a brief description about the study design and the data structure from Shakesbeery would be more helpful in understanding whether a random for word is valid or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You just use an ANOVA test for this like Stéphane and the help file of the package suggest!

```
>fm1 <- lmer(intdiff ~ stress * vowel_group + (1|speaker) + (1|word), data)
>fm2 <- lmer(intdiff ~ stress * vowel_group + (1|speaker), data)
>anova(fm1,fm2)
```

It doesn't matter whether you set the model with the fewest df first or second in the `anova` command, however it is important in the interpretation of the results that the model with the **least** df gets preferred in case of a significant difference.

Comment: Yup. This is what I needed. Credit also to @Stéphane Laurent for her reply.