# How to interpret anova output for mixed model likelihood ratio test

Tags: r, mixed-model, interpretation, likelihood-ratio, nonlinear

```
library(nlme)
fm1 <- nlme(height ~ SSasymp(age, Asym, R0, lrc),
            data = Loblolly,
            fixed = Asym + R0 + lrc ~ 1,
            random = Asym ~ 1,
            start = c(Asym = 103, R0 = -8.5, lrc = -3.3))
summary(fm1)
fm2 <- update(fm1, random = pdDiag(Asym + lrc ~ 1))
summary(fm2)
anova(fm1, fm2)

    Model df      AIC      BIC    logLik   Test  L.Ratio p-value
fm1     1  5 239.4856 251.6397 -114.7428                        
fm2     2  6 238.9662 253.5511 -113.4831 1 vs 2 2.519406  0.1125
```

I'm trying to see which model is preferred using an LRT. Here the p-value is > 0.05, so I fail to reject the null hypothesis and conclude that the smaller model `fm1` is sufficient. And if the p-value were < 0.05, then I would conclude that the larger model `fm2` is preferred. However, from reading [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49872/likelihood-ratio-tests-on-linear-mixed-effect-models) post, the top answer states that "the model with the least df gets preferred in case of a significant difference." So...does this mean that if p-value < 0.05, `fm1` would be preferred?

Comment: If you have a significant p-value you should use the model with the smaller AIC.

Comment: @Roland, so I should use the model with the smaller AIC instead of the smaller df? Could you elaborate?

Comment: non-significant p-value --> use model with smaller df; significant p-value --> use model with smaller AIC

Comment: @Roland, thanks for the response. In that case what you proposed (non-significant p-value --> use model with smaller df) is contradictory to the top answer in the post I referred to (the model with the least df gets preferred in case of a significant difference)?

Comment: DF tells you which model is more complex/simpler. The p-value tells you if the likelihoods can be considered different. None of these tell you which model fit can be considered better. The values of the likelihood (and AIC or BIC which are derived from it) can tell you that.